# Injected script slows down Google Maps related pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I'm injecting some html into page (extension written with angular.js) and on pages with google maps frames like airbnb the loading slows down. So I don't have any idea how I affect that. Any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific. Provide your code to let people see what you are doing. Your question is too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load JavaScript from a third party you should do it asynchronously. You might want to load your own scripts asynchronously too, but for this article let's focus on third parties.

There are two reasons for this:

1. If the third-party goes down or is slow, your page won't be held up
   trying to load that resource.
2. It can speed up page loads.

At Wufoo, we just switched over to an asynchronous embed snippet. Users who build forms with Wufoo and want to embed them on their site are now recommended to use it. We did it for exactly those reasons above. It's the responsible thing to do for a web service that asks people to link to resources on that services site.

There is a little terminology involved here that will help us understand the umbrella "asynchronous" term.

**"Parser blocking"** - The browser reads your HTML and when it comes to a  it downloads that entire resource before moving on with the parsing. This definitely slows down page loads, especially if the script is in the head or above any other visual elements. This is true in older browsers as well as modern browsers if you don't use the async attribute (more on that later). From the MDN docs: "In older browsers that don't support the async attribute, parser-inserted scripts block the parser..."

To prevent problematic parser blocking, scripts can be "script inserted" (i.e. insert another script with JavaScript) which then forces them to execute asynchronously (except in Opera or pre 4.0 Firefox).

**"Resource blocking"** - While a script is being downloaded, it can prevent other resources from downloading at the same time as it. IE 6 and 7 do this, only allowing one script to be downloaded at a time and nothing else. IE 8 and Safari 4 allow multiple scripts to download in parallel, but block any other resources (reference).

Ideally we fight against both of these problems and speed up page loading (both actual and perceived) speed.

https://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/